# How to create custom methods or functions inside imported models in Sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

I am totally a newbie to `Node.js`. It's my first project in node. Since I use Laravel for most of my projects I am familiar with MVC (Model View Controller).  So I went through the `Sequelize ORM` documentation regarding Models. I learned how to import one `model` per file and it worked  but when I added **custom functions** to the `User` model, the function works fine but doesn't return anything.

Here's my DB File

```
const fs = require('fs');
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database_name', 'userName', 'password', {
  host: 'localhost',
  dialect: 'mysql',
  operatorsAliases: false,
  logging:false,

  pool: {
    max: 5,
    min: 0,
    acquire: 30000,
    idle: 10000
  },

  // SQLite only
  //storage: 'path/to/database.sqlite'
});



sequelize.import('./../models/User.js');
var db=sequelize.models;



   module.exports={db,connectionCheck};
```

and here's User Model' Code

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var User = sequelize.define('User', {},{
         timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName:true,
        tableName:'agent_info'
      });
/*This is the custom function that I added*/
      User.test = function(){
         User.findOne().then(data =>{
           console.log(data);
           return data;
        });
      };


  return User;
};
```

and finally Route file's code

```
 app.get('/',(req,res,next) =>{
      var temp=db.User.test();
      console.log(temp);
    });
```

Here I am invoking `user.test()` function (Custom Model Function )
the function seems to work as expected, but isn't returning anything. So am I doing anything wrong, or it is not possible in Sequelize?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `test` function does not return anything its because `findOne` is async and return would happen before `findOne` is complete.

All you have to do is return the `User.findOne()` which in turn would return a promise. Something like this

```
User.test = () => User.findOne().then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  });
```

Now you can use 
`User.test().then((result) => { .. }` if you are using `promises` or
`const result = await User.test();` if you want to use `async/await`

PS: The `test` function here is a `class method`.

Comment: Thanks man it worked but data also returned a promise so i used another then call  in route file

Comment: Happy to help. You can then just return `User.test = () => User.findOne()`. and `console.log(data)` inside the `then`. No need for two `.then`

Comment: Would you clarify little bit more like how to use await and async

Comment: There are lot of articles like [this](https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/) and [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-write-beautiful-node-js-apis-using-async-await-and-the-firebase-database-befdf3a5ffee)